# (C#) Reference dlls inside dll

Tags: c#, dll, reference, linker

I wrote `databases.dll` and referenced 2 dlls inside.

```
Npgsql.dll and MySql.Data.dll
```

I compiled my project to databases.dll in command line like this:

```
csc.exe /target:library /r:Npgsql.dll,MySql.Data.dll /out:databases.dll PostgreSql.cs MySql.cs
```

`databases.dll` is compiled without problems.

Problem appears when I want to test it creating new project and reference `database.dll`.
Program is compiling but when it try to use dll code it brings the error: `TypeInitializationException was unhandled`.

I was trying to copy both dlls to the directory where the compilation target is.

I want to ask if there is possible to:

1. Create dll that reference to other dlls.
2. Provide dll to the enduser without referenced dlls and ask them to do so if they want to use each part of the dll. So when coder want to use MySql he have to provide `MySql.dll` to the compilation.

I hope I made myself clear cause my English ain't perfect ;)

Comment: There should be an inner exception to the TypeInitializationException. Check that; it may provide you with more insight into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As `Npgsql.dll` and `MySql.Data.dll` are both dependency DLLs, they both need to be referenced by your project in order for it to compile.

Comment: I am referencing both of them with "copy local"