# Can I encapsulate all of my dependencies inside my dll project?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

**My Current Situation:**

I have a main project, `Project_A`,
a dll project `Project_Parent_dll`
and another dll project `Project_Child_dll`.

`Project_Child_dll` contains a wpf user control.

`Project_Parent_dll` contains a wpf user control, that uses the user control contained in `Project_Child_dll`.
This Project contains a reference to `Project_Child_dll`.

`Project_A` uses the user control from `Project_Parent_dll`.
Right now, I have to reference both `Project_Parent_dll` and `Project_Child_dll`, and that works fine, but when I delete the reference to `Project_Child_dll` I get an XamlParseException.

**Question:**

Is there a way I could avoid the reference to `Project_Child_dll` in my `Project_A`?

Comment: PS: I found some duplicates like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523920/c-reference-dlls-inside-dll but with no answer.

Comment: Does the parent library project expose any properties (such as classes/enums) that rely on the child library?

Comment: A). Unify your child and parent into a single dll. If that is not an option, then you have no other option since your main project is dependent on both that is why the error occurred. B). Find the objects from the parent that are not dependent on child and use those for the main.

Comment: @DavidG: Definitely not in the C# portion of the dll, I am not sure how xaml works it's magic tough. Will it implicitly expose an element of my child dll if I use it in the parents xaml?